# page-break-after does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, page-break

I have a problem with `page-break-after` in Google Chrome during printing. It seems that it's not working. I tried Firefox and it's ok there. My code is:

```html
<div style="position: relative; display: block;">

    <div style="display: block; page-break-after: always; position: relative;">Page 1</div>

    <div style="display: block; position: relative; page-break-before:always;">Page 2</div>

</div>
```

Is there any trick to get it done in Chrome?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a hack, but Chrome doesn't support page-breaks very well. So try to use this instead:

```
<body>
    <main role="main">
        <section class="tabs">
            <div class="tabbed-content">
                <div class="break-after">Page 1</div>
                <div class="break-before">Page 2</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

And add this to your css:

```
html, body, .main, .tabs, .tabbed-content { float: none; }

.break-after {
    display: block;
    page-break-after: always;
    position: relative;
}

.break-before {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you only need display:block with page-break-before. position: relative is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

Please note for page-break to work, div should not have any float!

So if your div has say float:left , reset it for print saying: float: none and it will make page break work again.

Answer (score 5):

It should not be inside a flex div.
If it is, page break does not work unless flex div is closed.

Ex:

```
   <div class="row">
           //bla bla    
   </div>/*close old flex div*/
    <div class="col-12 p-0 display-block break-before"></div>
    <div class="row">/*new flex div*/
              //bla bla
    </div>
    <style>
    .break-before {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        page-break-before: always !important;   
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the previous answers to work in Chrome in October 2019. It now seems to be the case that `break-before: page` has to be used rather than `break-before: always`.

This also works in FF, but so do previous answers.

```
<div>
  <div class="break-before">
    Page 1
  </div>
  <div class="break-before">
    Page 2
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.break-before {
  break-before: page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had button row and i wanted to break into 2 lines with 3rd button so i used this

```
button:nth-of-type(3) {
   page-break-after: right;
}
```

but this didn't work with chrome because it is a **flex** (i think)

so as alternative i used grid like this

```
.partent-class-options {
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

this is only alternative but not accurate like [break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)
as you know this will not work for the patterns like first row contain 3 options and second one contains more than 3 ✌️