# page-break-* css doesn't work on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, page-break

I have a card view for report and I want to display each card on each page when the report gets printed. I was trying to achieve this by using the page-break css.

```
.card-view {
     page-break-after: always;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

But this is not working as expected. The card view breaks inside.
I tried to fix this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871701/9857763), but even that is not working for me.

page-break works on edge but why isn't it working on Chrome?
Is there any alternative way to get this done?

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks) might help.

Comment: @luenib Currently i am doing it the same way, but its now working