# Google Chrome not accepting page-breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I 've been stuck on getting print styles to work fine on both browsers with no luck so far. Page-breaks seem to work fine in IE but Chrome is not accepting it. I am using this code within my html to break up the sections:

`<div style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</div>`

And..in my print styles I am targeting this div id. Both browsers can print the jumbotron with no issue, but its just that Chrome is not taking in the page break.

```
#jumbotron {
    background-color: white !important; 
    height: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: normal !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    display: block !important;

}
#jumbotron{
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

A couple things I also tried were:

- remove the absolute position on the jumbotron(which fixes the issue on Chrome) BUT generates a blank PDF on IE.
- Tried to apply page-break-after: always !important: but this made no difference

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [page-break-after does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871451/page-break-after-does-not-work-in-chrome)